# How does one call a function from a postgresql rule that has access to NEW and OLD?

Tags: postgresql, rules

I'm new to postgresql (and therefore rules) and I've looked around, but can't really find an example calling a 'global' function.

I am using a normalized database where rows will be flagged as deleted rather than deleted. However, I would like to retain the `DELETE FROM...` functionality for the end user, by using an instead of delete rule to update the table's `deleted_time` column. Each table should, therefore, be able to use a common function, but I am not sure how this would be called in this context, or how it would have access to `NEW` and `OLD`?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE rule_tablename_delete AS ON DELETE
TO tablename DO INSTEAD (
   /// call function here to update the table's delete_time column
);
```

Is this even the correct approach? (I note that INSTEAD OF triggers are restricted to views only)

Comment: Rules are generally deprecated in Pg and have a lot of subtle behaviors that can surprise you. Unfortunately, BEFORE DELETE ... FOR EACH ROW triggers don't seem to support ignoring the DELETE operation yet; as you note, you need an INSTEAD OF trigger and they're only supported on views so far. I guess you're stuck with a rule for now, but I'd suggest re-evaluating this with new releases. Consider posting on pgsql-general too - cases triggers don't cover need to be highlighted and the TODO needs to be updated since it doesn't mention INSTEAD OF triggers on tables.

Answer (score 4):

Just use an UPDATE statement:

```
create rule rule_tablename_delete as
  on delete to tablename
do instead
   update tablename 
      set delete_time = current_timestamp
    where id = old.id
      and delete_time is null;
```

Assuming that the `id` column is the primary key of that table.

Some more examples are in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/rules-update.html

Comment: Thanks - how would one insure the delete_time here? (Attempting to delete the row again would update the timestamp). Is the answer to add a 'delete_time is null' clause to the rule, then create a second rule to DO NOTHING when it is not null? (otherwise it will be deleted)

Comment: @videocakes: sure, if you add the `where delete_time is null` then the update won't update anything, but the rule will still be considered as "executed" thus the delete will never happen.